# How do __builtin_ia32_unpcklps/hps and __builtin_ia32_movlhps/hlps work?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, sse, built-in

I am looking optimized ways to do matrix transpose on CPU only with a known cache set number and block size.  I found that the Intel intrinsic functions contained a low-level transpose of a 4x4 matrix. As follows:

```
#define _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(row0, row1, row2, row3)           \
do {                                    \
  __v4sf __r0 = (row0), __r1 = (row1), __r2 = (row2), __r3 = (row3);    \
  __v4sf __t0 = __builtin_ia32_unpcklps (__r0, __r1);           \
  __v4sf __t1 = __builtin_ia32_unpcklps (__r2, __r3);           \
  __v4sf __t2 = __builtin_ia32_unpckhps (__r0, __r1);           \
  __v4sf __t3 = __builtin_ia32_unpckhps (__r2, __r3);           \
  (row0) = __builtin_ia32_movlhps (__t0, __t1);             \
  (row1) = __builtin_ia32_movhlps (__t1, __t0);             \
  (row2) = __builtin_ia32_movlhps (__t2, __t3);             \
  (row3) = __builtin_ia32_movhlps (__t3, __t2);             \
} while (0)
```

The functions its using are built-in GCC compiler functions which use the UNPCKHPS/LPS and MOVLHPS/HLPS x86 assembly commands.  That I understand and I roughly understand how those commands would work together to transpose the 4 rows.

However, I wanted to test these functions and so I copy this into my code and edited it slightly.

I found that simiply subsituting the function into the arguments with out using a temporary varible broke the function.  Here is an example of that:

```
#define _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(row0, row1, row2, row3)           \
do {                                    \
  __v4sf __r0 = (row0), __r1 = (row1), __r2 = (row2), __r3 = (row3);    \
  __v4sf __t1 = __builtin_ia32_unpcklps (__r2, __r3);           \
  __v4sf __t2 = __builtin_ia32_unpckhps (__r0, __r1);           \
  __v4sf __t3 = __builtin_ia32_unpckhps (__r2, __r3);           \
  (row0) = __builtin_ia32_movlhps (__builtin_ia32_unpcklps (__r0, __r1), __t1);             \
  (row1) = __builtin_ia32_movhlps (__t1, __builtin_ia32_unpcklps (__r0, __r1));             \
  (row2) = __builtin_ia32_movlhps (__t2, __t3);             \
  (row3) = __builtin_ia32_movhlps (__t3, __t2);             \
} while (0)
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?  Normally, if you change the order of function calls (assuming that they aren't operating on the same pointer) cannot effect execution.

Comment: How did you test it to find out it was broken?  Looks like they compile identically with gcc https://godbolt.org/z/DOcbHs unless I'm missing something.  But clang doesn't support `__builtin_ia32_unpckhps`.  Are you on OS X where the `gcc` command is actually `clang`?

Comment: Did you look at the disassembly of both variants (good one and bad one) and check the difference?

Comment: If you're going to rewrite it, I'd suggest start by using an inline function rather than macro.  I don't know why Intel(?) used a macro for this, but there hasn't been a reason to use macros to do this with GCC in 30 years.

Comment: I just tested both variants of your code using different random data. I also tested different compiler settings (unoptimized and `-O`). gcc compiler was version 7.4.0, 64-bit, Ubuntu Linux: Both variants had the same results. So if both variants have different results on your computer, this might be a compiler issue.

Comment: @PeterCordes Shouldn't the user get some linker error if his compiler doesn't support `__builtin_ia32_unpckhps`?

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Yes, I would expect that.  Maybe Apple clang is different from mainline clang on Godbolt.  Or maybe "broke the function" is just a really terrible description of the problem, and does mean linker error!  Clearly we need a [mcve] + compiler version and options.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  I'm using gcc with -std=c99 and I'm on Ubuntu, not OS X.  When I use that site you provided and compile as C code, not C++, it does give somewhat different compilation for the two.  I have worked out exactly where in here the problem is yet: https://godbolt.org/z/0myXso I think it may have to do with the unpcklps command using the second argument as the destination but I am not sure.